# How to get IF Function in spreadsheet based on data in column C and D to count amount of size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need if function to count amount of size from column in C and D automatically.
Could anybody help me?
I count it manually by sorting male and female first then I used formula =COUNTIF(C2:C6,"XXL") to get how many male with size XXL.

Below is the picture in spreadsheet, and the green color is the result I want.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcdM7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear `E:J` and put it in `E1`

```
=QUERY(C:D,"select D,count(D) where D is not null group by D pivot C",1)
```

---

Or only clear `G:G` and `J:J`, put it to `G2` first and then copy and apply to `J2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="",,COUNTIFS($D:$D,E2:E,$C:$C,E1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use
=QUERY(A1:D, ”SELECT D, COUNT(D) GROUP BY D PIVOT C”,
1)